# Integrate Wordpress with ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, integration

I want to integrate Wordpress on my .NET website. I have already read this can be difficult, however, the integration I'm looking for appears to be rather straightforward to me.
The only area of my site that needs to be Wordpress enabled is the `/articles` part of my website.
This means that the Wordpress articles will need to adopt the style of my .NET masterpage.
My thought now is that this should be possible by having Wordpress serve articles without a design applied to it (just the raw HTML without CSS), so that I may apply the CSS of my current .NET website.

Is this possible without iframing the Wordpress content and if so how to set that up in Wordpress?
And will it also be possible to have the facetted navigation structure of article tags that Wordpress offers out of the box?

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered getting article content directly from db? this will give you maximum control on the design.

Comment: if you want to still serve via wordpress try changing the theme to your masterpage.

Comment: i'm not an server infrastructure guru, but is it possible to create a virtual directory '/articles' to a part of the server where you place your wordpress install?

Comment: @Ratna: that's a good suggestion! I'll look into that! :)